# How do I use getApplication() inside a Spinner's onItemSelected() inside a fragment?

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, fragment

I'm trying to use `getApplication()` inside a `Spinner`'s `onItemSelected()` method to try and get a `ViewModel` using `ViewModelProviders`. I'm like 4 inner classes deep at this point, and I encounter a `java.lang.NullPointerException` crash seconds after launch this activity.

The question title sums my problem up pretty accurately.

Here is the `Fragment`'s `onCreateView()` method:

```
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_menu, container, false);
        final MenuActivity menuAct = (MenuActivity) getActivity();
        final MenuViewModel viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this, new MenuViewModelFactory(menuAct.getApplication(), MenuActivity.ResID)).get(MenuViewModel.class);
        viewModel.getAllMenuTitles().observe(this, new Observer<String[]>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(String[] strings) {
                final Spinner spinner = rootView.findViewById(R.id.spinner);
                ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(), R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item, strings);
                adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

                spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                        menuAct.removeAllTabs();
                        SubMenuViewModel vm = ViewModelProviders.of(getParentFragment(), new SubMenuViewModelFactory(menuAct.getApplication(), i)).get(SubMenuViewModel.class); //← This is the problematic getApplication() 
                        vm.getSubMenus().observe(getActivity(), new Observer<String[]>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onChanged(@Nullable String[] strings) {
                                menuAct.populateTabs(strings);
                            }
                        });
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

                    }
                });
            }
        });

        return rootView;
    }
```

Here is my stack trace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity android.support.v4.app.Fragment.getActivity()' on a null object reference
    at android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModelProviders.checkActivity(ViewModelProviders.java:50)
    at android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModelProviders.of(ViewModelProviders.java:100)
    at com.whatamidoingwithmylife.splitbill.MenuActivity$PlaceholderFragment$1$1.onItemSelected(MenuActivity.java:198)
    at android.widget.AdapterView.fireOnSelected(AdapterView.java:944)
    at android.widget.AdapterView.dispatchOnItemSelected(AdapterView.java:933)
    at android.widget.AdapterView.-wrap1(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.widget.AdapterView$SelectionNotifier.run(AdapterView.java:898)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:440)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

Comment: Are you sure that's the failing line and not the one following it? The error message says the error is from `getActivity()` on line 198. Why not use `menuAct` on the following line instead of `getActivity()`?

Comment: I am sure. When I click `MenuActivity;198` on the stack trace, the commented line is the one that's highlighted. I didn't use `menuAct` on that line because I don't know if it works yet.

Answer (score 0):

Override **onAttach()** to get the activity as follows,

```java
private Activity mActivity;

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);

    if (context instanceof Activity){
        mActivity=(Activity) context;
    }

}
```

then use **mActivity.getApplication()** to access the application object.

If you want the application context, you can get the application context from the adapterView,

> **adapterView.getContext().getApplicationContext()**

If your fragment is attached to MenuActivity then you can get the application object as follows,

> **((MenuActivity)adapterView.getContext()).getApplication()**

Comment: I'm trying to `getApplication()`, not `getApplicationContext()`. ViewModelProviders wants me to pass an `application`, not a `context`.

Comment: Do you want to pass the application object to access it's method?

Comment: I want to only pass the Application object.

Comment: @SikuM. I updated the answer to get the application object

Comment: @SikuM. please override your fragments onAttach() as shown in the updated answer, since you are getting null for getActivity() which happens sometime, it's better to get the activity on fragment attach.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176898/discussion-between-mrah-and-siku-m).